# Href properties of the main menu items are empty just on the live site

Tags: joomla, joomla4

I have updated a website from Joomla 3 to Joomla 4 on my local machine. When I upload it all the main menu items are shown on the frontend with the HREF fields empty.

I can't understand why this is happening. On my local machine, everything works fine.

If I open a menu item in the menu manager and copy its URL and add it to the homepage link the subpage opens correctly.

I lost a couple of hours trying to understand the cause.

Do you have any idea of what can be the cause of this issue?

[image: The code that shows menu items missing the href attribute]